# SharePoint 2013 REST view item with space in fieldname

Tags: rest, sharepoint-2013, spaces

I have the following to look up my standard fields in SharePoint 2013:

```
var requestURI = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listname + "')/items?" +
    "$select=ID,Title,Status";

$.ajax({
    url: requestURI,
    method: "GET",
    headers: {"Accept": "application/json odata=verbose", "content/type" : "application/json odata=verbose"},
    success: function(data) {
        $.each(data.d.results, function(index, item) {
            console.log('ID: ' + item.ID);
            console.log('Title: ' + item.Title);
            console.log('Status: ' + item.Status);
        }
    }
```

This works fine in returning those three items.  I have a problem that I have a field I need to retrieve that has a space in it, "Suspense Status".  I had used SPServices previously with SharePoint 2007 and this webPart.  With it, I would use "Suspense_x0020_Status" to reference the feield.  I have tried that with REST as this:

```
            console.log('Suspense Status: ' + item.Suspense_x0020_Status);
```

with no luck, as expected, but I am uncertain how to go about getting this information.  I have tried a way to look at the JSON XML keys, but haven't had luck doing that either.

Does anyone know ho I could do either, reference the field with a space in its name, or look up all the field names referenced in the sharepoint list?  Or both?

Thank You

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OK, I found the problem.  The '*x0020*' works fine!!!!!

I neglected to include the field, 'Suspense_x0020_Status' in my '$select=' statement to make it '$select=ID,Title,Status,Suspense_x0020_Status'.

It appears to be going fine now.

Sorry for the trouble.